# Bounty Distribution Equalization

Tags: algorithm, math, distribution

I need an algorithm, like the one used in Travian. I want to know how to make it so that there are 4 resource types, and when someone raids, they take so much, but they take equal of a percentage from each resource type depending on how much is available for the raid. So lets say I can raid 450 resources, but the defender has 300 wood, 400 clay, 200 iron, and 100 wheat, I would take the percentage of however much the wood constitutes the total resources, then I would multiply that to the bounty. The problem is when I round, I get someimes 449/450 or 451/450.

So are there any ways to solve the rounding problems, and is it possible for someone to compile the whole algorithm? I was just very curious, like I usually am and compile tons of algorithms out of curiosity like Elo, Torus, and other very basic algorithms.

Comment: why don't you round it down? Perhaps I don't understand the question.

Comment: Well, the problem is I want it to all add up to a certain number.

Answer (score 3):

You can calculate the remainder using [modulo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation), and distribute the remainder randomly.

Answer (score 3):

If you want them to all be "equally distributed", then you'll have the occasional rounding problem. If my capacity is 100 and there are three equal resources, you'll never be able to get it right with just rounding.

If it happens, just choose one to "fix" it. I'd normally go with the last resource. Just round all but the last like you normally do, and then subtract them all from the total(450 or in your example), and that's what your last resource value is.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want your raiders to take a percentage corresponding to the raided town resources ? 
According to me raiders should pick up a balanced amount of each resource according to their capacity.

With your example :

```
Raiders capacity - 450
Wood - 300
Clay - 400
Iron - 200
Wheat - 100

While  Not Empty (Wood and clay and Iron and Wheat) and Not Full ( Raiders )
    Raiders pick up 1 each ressources
```

After this step Raiders have `400` resources (because there is no more Wheat).

town Stack

```
Wood - 200
Clay - 300
Iron - 100
Wheat - 0
```

Do the same for remaining resources :
`50 / 3 = 16`

After this Raiders stack is like it :

```
Wood - 116
Clay - 116
Iron - 116
Wheat - 100
TOTAL : 448
```

Then you have two solutions, picking resources in largest stack or just continue your loop.
if you choose to pick up resources in largest :

Current Stock :

```
Wood - 184
Clay - 284
Iron - 84
Wheat - 0
TOTAL : 552
```

Pick 2 units of Clay then you have following result :

**Town Stack**

```
Wood - 184
Clay - 282
Iron - 84
Wheat - 0
TOTAL : 550
```

**Raiders stack**

```
Wood - 116
Clay - 118
Iron - 116
Wheat - 100
TOTAL : 450
```

It is just another point of view. Is it interesting according to you ?